# T current property vs IEnumerator current c#

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I implementing a generic version of IEnumerable and IEnumerator. in IEnumerator i have two current property 
1- T current 
2- IEnumerator.Current
first: why i have two current property?
second: when i put debug point in second property i saw that this property never execute and when i change return value from this property nothing in my code changed.
please someone describe that

```
public class Seller<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T[] _array;

    public Seller(T[] list)
    {
        _array = list;
    }


    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return  new UserDefinedEnum<T>(_array);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}


public class UserDefinedEnum<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    int _index = -1;

    T[] _array;

    public UserDefinedEnum(T[] list)
    {
        _array = list;
    }

    public T Current
    {

        get
        {
            return _array[_index];
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _index++;
        return _index < _array.Length;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _index = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> first: why i have two current property?

Because the generic `IEnumerator<T>` inherits the non-generic `IEnumerator` interface. You need to implement both interfaces, and `T Current { get; }` doesn't satisfy the `object Current { get; }` member of `IEnumerator`.  (`T` may not be a reference type.)

> second: when i put debug point in second property i saw that this property never execute and when i change return value from this property nothing in my code changed.

Because nothing in your code is treating an instance as `IEnumerator`; everything is accessing it as an `IEnumerator<T>`.

If you assign a `Seller<T>` object reference to an `IEnumerable` (*not* `IEnumerable<T>`) and then write a `foreach` loop over that, you *will* see the `object IEnumerable.Current` getter invoked.

Answer (score 0):

See [IEnumerator.Current Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1.current?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerator_1_Current)

> Notes to Implementers
>
> Implementing this interface requires implementing the nongeneric IEnumerator interface. The Current property appears on both interfaces, and has different return types. Implement the nongeneric Current property as an explicit interface implementation. This allows any consumer of the nongeneric interface to consume the generic interface.